# R: fully justified of strwrap

Tags: r

There is a function example to wrap text
Ref: [Text wrap for plot titles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367138/text-wrap-for-plot-titles)
But how can I get the text to be both left and right hand side justified?
 (justified—text is aligned along the left margin, and letter- and word-spacing is adjusted so that the text falls flush with both margins, also known as fully justified or full justification).

```
plot(rnorm(100), main = paste(
strwrap(
'This is a very long title wrapped on multiple lines without the need to adjust it by hand',
whitespace_only = TRUE,
width = 50
  ),
 collapse = "\n"
))
```

Comment: When I run your code I get the error: `unused argument (whitespace_only = TRUE)` and a quick check of `?strwrap` reveals no such parameter.

Comment: `stri_wrap` from the `stringi` package does however have a `whitespace_only=` argument. I think you might have a typo.

Comment: Relevant maybe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710597/justify-text-in-r

Comment: I didn't understand your question, u want left or right of your title justifed ? or both ?

Comment: I wanted both. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a standard plotting parameter described on the help page `?par`.  For left justification, you need the parameter `adj = 0`

```
plot(rnorm(100), main = paste(
strwrap(
'This is a very long title wrapped on multiple lines without the need to adjust it by hand',
width = 50), collapse = "\n" ), adj=0)
```

[image: Left Justified title]

For right justified,  use `adj=1`.

Comment: A very non-obvious solution (+1).

Comment: Is it possible to justify both left and right habd sides at the same time?

Comment: @adam.888  I am not 100% sure what you mean. My guess is that you mean to insert enough blanks in the center so that the string fills the space. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Thanks. This is what I mean: justified—text is aligned along the left margin, and letter- and word-spacing is adjusted so that the text falls flush with both margins, also known as fully justified or full justification