# How can I align the text of a paragraph in the user interface of a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

So I am creating a shiny app and imagine I have a chunk of text like this:

```
Download the tsv data set with specimen and COI-5P 
sequence data belonging to the taxonomic group 
chosen from the BOLD database. Filtered out the following 
from the dataset
```

I want it to be aligned and justified like you do on microsoft word
How can I make it look something like this:

```
Download the tsv data set with specimen and COI-5P 
sequence data belonging to the taxonomic group ch-
sen from the BOLD database. Filtered out the foll-
owing from the dataset
```

Thanks for any responses in advance

Comment: this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710597/justify-text-in-r

Comment: I think you have to use one of the html functions. Try put the text inside tags$div(style="text-align:justify", "your text")